# C++/WinRT DeviceInformation No default Constructor exists error

Tags: c++, c++17, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

Hello i'm trying to port the following code from a c# program.

```
 public class DeviceListEntry
 {
     private DeviceInformation device;
     private String deviceSelector;

     public String InstanceId
     {
         get
         {
             return device.Properties[DeviceProperties.DeviceInstanceId] as String;
         }
     }

     public DeviceInformation DeviceInformation
     {
         get
         {
             return device;
         }
     }

     public String DeviceSelector
     {
         get
         {
             return deviceSelector;
         }
     }

     /// <summary>
     /// The class is mainly used as a DeviceInformation wrapper so that the UI can bind to a list of these.
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="deviceInformation"></param>
     /// <param name="deviceSelector">The AQS used to find this device</param>
     public DeviceListEntry(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation deviceInformation, String deviceSelector)
     {
         device = deviceInformation;
         this.deviceSelector = deviceSelector;
     }

 }
}
```

Essentially if I attempt to port the DeviceListEntry Constructor with the deviceInformation object it errors me saying there is no default Constructor for the DeviceInformation Class.

however if I remove the corresponding code for the device object the DevuceListEntry constructor doesn't return any errors.

Here's what I have:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "DeviceListEntry.h"
#include "Constants.h"
using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections;

namespace SerialArduino
{

    const winrt::hstring DeviceProperties::DeviceInstanceID = {L"System.Devices.DeviceInstanceId"};


    // having a DeviceInformation object as parameter as well as object causes no default constructor error
    DeviceListEntry::DeviceListEntry(winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation deviceInformation, winrt::hstring deviceSelector)
    {
        device = deviceInformation;
        this->deviceSelector = deviceSelector;
    }

    winrt::hstring DeviceListEntry::InstanceId()
    {

        return winrt::unbox_value<winrt::hstring>(device.Properties().Lookup(DeviceProperties::DeviceInstanceID));
    
    }

    winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation DeviceListEntry::DeviceInformation()
    {
        return device;
    }

    winrt::hstring DeviceListEntry::DeviceSelector()
    {
        return deviceSelector;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Error (active)  E0291   no default constructor exists for class 
Error   C2512   'winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation': no appropriate default constructor available SerialArduino
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm completely lost on what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the full error diagnostic (from the compiler output, not Visual Studio's error list). Also show a [mcve]. It sounds like you're trying to instantiate a class without providing any arguments, but that class doesn't have a default constructor. It's not clear what that class is, nor why you are trying to invoke the default constructor.

Comment: My apologies I thought this was Thorough enough, next time I have a question I will make sure to include what you have specified. Paolo was right on the money with what my issue was though!

Comment: You can [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71867891/edit) your question at any time to include the required information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `DeviceListEntry` declaration looks like:

```
namespace SerialArduino {

class DeviceListEntry {
public:
    //...

private:
    winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation device;
    winrt::hstring deviceSelector;
};

}
```

Try implementing your constructor like this:

```
// having a DeviceInformation object as parameter as well as object causes no default constructor error
DeviceListEntry::DeviceListEntry(winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation deviceInformation, winrt::hstring deviceSelector_)
    : device(deviceInformation), deviceSelector(deviceSelector_)
{ }
```

This way, `device` will be copy-initialized from `deviceInformation`.

Otherwise, the compiler will try to default-construct `device` and then copy-assign `deviceInformation` to it.